# area or area size?

Tags: word-usage

When talking about the growth of a production plant, which of the following is correct, and why?

> We are growing in area and number of employees.

Or:

> We are growing in area size and number of employees.

Comment: @All Please remember that answers go in the answer box. Comments are for requesting clarification of the question.

Answer (score 1):

"area size" is not an idiomatic phrase. "area" already refers to the amount of space, adding "size" is redundant.

So "growing in area" is the more correct one of the two phrases.

Answer (score 0):

A colloquialism is **[footprint](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20company%27s%20footprint%20in%20the%20pacific%20rim&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=the%20company%27s%20footprint%20in%20the%20pacific%20rim&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.239007613j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**.

As the attestations show, it is a very common phrase in the context of business expansion, and so anyone who reads about business is not likely to confuse it with "environmental footprint" or "carbon footprint" which are a measure of a company's deleterious effects upon the planet's natural environment.

> The company's footprint is getting larger. Not only has our workforce doubled in size, we have purchased land and built new facilities.

Comment: This doesn't work. I've only heard "footprint" as being short for "environmental footprint" which is also the only relevant definition in my dictionary (NOAD).

Comment: @Laurel: I think it can work - eg it can mean [the shape on the ground that is covered by something such as a building](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/footprint).

Comment: @Laurel You didn't look very hard, especially given your emphatic "This doesn't work."  https://www.google.com/search?q=the+company%27s+footprint+in+the+pacific+rim&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&oq=the+company%27s+footprint+in+the+pacific+rim&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l2.239007613j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Dictionaries are "lagging indicators", as we say. The word has to exist before the editors of the dictionary recognize it. The dictionaries don't confer existence upon the word, merely recognition.

Comment: @TimR That's something to put in the post itself, though you're not going to convince me that it's *not* confusing.

Comment: Without the word *environmental* it wont confuse anyone but the easily confused.  It is a very common usage, especially in business expansion contexts, which is OP's context.

Comment: Without further context, "footprint" will likely be interpreted as figurative, not literal - as the example suggests, a company's footprint consists of their general impact on the workforce, economy, and society. I would not take it in the literal sense of increasing the square footage of the company's real estate - a company can increase its footprint by expanding into new markets or hiring more people with no change whatsoever to the physical size of the workplace.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie  The word has been used for over 10 years now in business-oriented journals, newspapers, and online organs (Wall Street Journal, MIT.edu, BusinessWire, for example) to include both increased market presence and increased physical plant/manufacturing capability.  If a person  reads business news they will have no problem understanding it, and I assume OP's target audience is comprised of such readers. His sample sentence suggests as much. Who else would be interested in a company's physical plant expansion?

Comment: @TimR Exactly, my point is that this term refers to a whole host of other aspects of a business beyond its physical size, which seems to be the only aspect the OP wants to capture.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie "A whole host" is a grotesque exaggeration.  The term  **footprint** refers to **presence**  and the statement being made identifies the kind of presence. That's how language works. There isn't a separate word for everything under the sun.

Answer (score 0):

In the US you are likely to hear *square footage*, meaning area when measured in units of square feet.

You might also hear *floor space* or *floor area* to indicate the interior area of a building.

In your examples, I don't believe "area size" would be commonly used because it is redundant. Either *area* or *size* might be used alone, as in

> We are increasing the size/area/floor space/square footage of our production facility.